# Is there any way to find a timer in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, timer

I have 2 div´s, the first where i have to click with right button, the other one is the custom context menu. I wish to hide the menu when user move the mouse away from both of the div´s. So i use `mouseout event` and `timer`. On `mouseover` the timer must go cleared, but something going wrong, to understand it i wish look in the timer object "on run". But if I make a breakpoint after timer creation (`setTimeout`), I will see only a some integer in the value, that i have assigned to the timer. How i can look in the timer it self?

UPD: I wish to know, where here and how i can find the timer data:
[image]

Comment: And your code is ?.....

Comment: Hmmmm, for what? I wish to know how I can see the timer in DOM, not where the point of error.

Answer (score 0):

An example of code for the time. I hope it's what you want. Otherwise, for more help, show us a part of your code.

```
var start

thediv = document.getElementById("idofdiv")
thediv.onmouseover = function() {
    begin = new Date().getTime();
}

thediv.onmouseout = function() {
    end = new Date().getTime();
    alert((end - begin) + ' seconds')
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, i hope you understand now, what i looking for.